# How to restrict all links and redirect to the same page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have used profile2 module and have created a separate profile type.
 The case is that, i have a profile edit form for the profile type named restaurant. Once the user logged in( with the role restaurant), he will be redirected to the profile edit page, where the user have to fill all the required fields of the profile form. If the user clicks any other links on the page he must be redirected to the same form with a msg (U have to complete the form ) till the user fill all the fields in the profile edit form.

i have done with redirecting the user to the profile edit form. Now i have to do the other part( links redirect with set msg). Is there any module i can use to get the above scenario or i have to do it by custom code. Please help me out if i have to do this by custom code..
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Hope this can do it. You can have a hidden variable in the profile edit form set to true if all the form elements are not empty. If not it should be set to false, and whenever the user clicks on the link check for the hidden element to be true; allow the navigation (by javascript code). If the element is set to false, do not allow the navigation, show them an error message.

Answer (score 0):

To make it working on all the pages and links, you should write some profile field value checking code in hook_page_alter or hook_page_build. If the values are empty, you should redirect the user.